# Draw along SVG path

Tags: algorithm, svg, canvas, html5-canvas

I have an SVG path which uses Bezier curves like:

```
m 776,2226 c 0,0 258.61385,-173.7593 289.34025,-325.8576 57.158,-282.9367 15.5277,-622.2212 50.8732,-933.13714 12.8345,-112.89946 104.2775,-278.6582 22.2568,-340.66923 -50.5144,-38.19103 -158.97817,99.97904 -158.97817,99.97904
```

In my application, I would like to start from the initial point (x=776, y=2226), and slowly draw the path. For example, when user presses a button, path will reveal a little more.

I want to do this using HTML canvas.

Note that this path is not a closed path.

I thought about using Canvas' `isPointInPath()` function, start from the initial point, and draw pixels one by one. However, how to find all points in the path?

What would be the alternative way for this?

Comment: Be sure to understand SVGs ``pathLength`` attribute before you dive into calculations: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pathLength

Answer (score 1):

Just like in SVG, the Canvas2D API has dash-offset and stroke-dasharray options, through the [`lineDashOffset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/lineDashOffset) property and [setLineDash](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/setLineDash) method respectively.

However, this API still lacks a proper way to measure the length of a path (there are early discussions about extending the Path2D API, but nothing concrete yet).
You could calculate yourself that length, but the more complex the path, the more probable you'll get it wrong...
So the easiest might actually be to use an SVGGeometry element, which does expose a `.getTotalLength()` method.

```js
const declaration = `M 10,30
       A 20,20 0,0,1 50,30
       A 20,20 0,0,1 90,30
       Q 90,60 50,90
       Q 10,60 10,30 z`;

const geom = document.createElementNS( "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path" );
geom.setAttribute( "d", declaration );
const length = geom.getTotalLength();

const path = new Path2D( declaration );
const canvas = document.querySelector( "canvas" );
const ctx = canvas.getContext( "2d" );
// [ dash - hole ]
ctx.setLineDash( [ length, length ] );

const duration = 2000;
const start = performance.now();
requestAnimationFrame( draw );

ctx.fillStyle = "green";
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";

function draw(now) {
  ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
  const delta = (now % duration) / duration;
  ctx.lineDashOffset = length - (length * delta);
  ctx.stroke( path );
  requestAnimationFrame( draw );
}
```

```html
<canvas width="100" height="100"></canvas>
```

And for the ones that came here for the title and want to move a shape along a path, we can keep using our SVGGeometryElement and its [getPointAtLength](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGeometryElement/getPointAtLength) method:

```js
const declaration = `M 10,30
       A 20,20 0,0,1 50,30
       A 20,20 0,0,1 90,30
       Q 90,60 50,90
       Q 10,60 10,30 z`;

const geom = document.createElementNS( "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path" );
geom.setAttribute( "d", declaration );
const length = geom.getTotalLength();

const path = new Path2D( declaration );
const canvas = document.querySelector( "canvas" );
const ctx = canvas.getContext( "2d" );

const duration = 2000;
const start = performance.now();
requestAnimationFrame( draw );

ctx.fillStyle = "green";
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";

function draw(now) {
  ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
  const delta = (now % duration) / duration;
  const point = geom.getPointAtLength( length * delta );
  ctx.fillRect( point.x - 10, point.y -10, 20, 20 );
  ctx.stroke( path );
  requestAnimationFrame( draw );
}
```

```html
<canvas width="100" height="100"></canvas>
```

Now, in your case I guess you'll still have a bit of work to scale correctly the returned values the same way you probably scale your path when drawing on your canvas, but I'll let that as an exercise (nothing too complex).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `stroke-dashoffset`? There is a good little explainer and [demo on CSS-Tricks.](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/stroke-dashoffset/)

Answer (score 0):

I did some research on the math of Bezier curves and also how they're represented in SVG.

My path was using an `m` command to denote the starting point of the path and a `c` command to denote a Bezier curve with **relative** control points and endpoint. The curve had multiple segments though.

A sample path of

```
m 1,2 c 3,4 5,6 7,8 9,10 11,12 13,14
```

means:

- Start point for the path is (1,2)
- Then comes a curve with 2 segments
- First segment starts at (1,2), its first control point is at (1+3,2+4)=(4,6), second control point is at (1+5,2+6)=(6,8) and it ends at (1+7,2+8)=(8,10)
- Second segment starts at the end point of the last one, (8,10). Its first control point is (8+9,10+10)=(18,19), second control point is (8+11,10+13)=(18,24), and the end point is (8+13,10+14)=(18,27)

Using the math of Bezier curves, I wrote this code to return the points on a Bezier curve with multiple segments. Please note that it only handles the scenario where the path is starting with an `m` and then it continues with a `c` command.

```
const POINTS_IN_SEGMENT = 6;

    class Point {
        x;
        y;

        constructor(xStr, yStr) {
            this.x = parseInt(xStr, 10);
            this.y = parseInt(yStr, 10);
        }

        add(other) {
            return new Point(this.x + other.x, this.y + other.y);
        }
    }

    class BezierCurveSegment {
        startPoint;
        controlPoint1;
        controlPoint2;
        endPoint;

        constructor(startPoint, controlPoint1, controlPoint2, endPoint) {
            this.startPoint = startPoint;
            this.controlPoint1 = controlPoint1;
            this.controlPoint2 = controlPoint2;
            this.endPoint = endPoint;
        }

        getPointsOnSegment(accuracy) {
            const points = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < 1; i += accuracy) {
                const p = bezier(i, this.startPoint, this.controlPoint1, this.controlPoint2, this.endPoint);
                points.push(new Point(p.x, p.y));
            }
            return points;
        }
    }

    class BezierCurve {
        startPoint;
        segments;

        constructor(startPoint, segments) {
            this.startPoint = startPoint;
            this.segments = segments;
        }

        getPointsOnCurve(pointCount) {
            const accuracy = 1 / pointCount * this.segments.length;
            let points = [];
            for (let segment of this.segments) {
                let pointsOnSegment = segment.getPointsOnSegment(accuracy);
                points = points.concat(pointsOnSegment);
            }
            return points;
        }
    }

    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227300/
    function bezier(t, p0, p1, p2, p3) {
        // console.log("bezier", t, p0, p1, p2, p3)
        var cX = 3 * (p1.x - p0.x),
                bX = 3 * (p2.x - p1.x) - cX,
                aX = p3.x - p0.x - cX - bX;

        var cY = 3 * (p1.y - p0.y),
                bY = 3 * (p2.y - p1.y) - cY,
                aY = p3.y - p0.y - cY - bY;

        var x = (aX * Math.pow(t, 3)) + (bX * Math.pow(t, 2)) + (cX * t) + p0.x;
        var y = (aY * Math.pow(t, 3)) + (bY * Math.pow(t, 2)) + (cY * t) + p0.y;

        return {x: x, y: y};
    }

    function createCurveFromSVGPath(pathStr) {
        pathStr = pathStr.replaceAll(',', ' ');
        let items = pathStr.split(' ');

        if (items[0] !== "m") {
            throw "First item in the path is not 'm' command (only relative is supported)";
        }
        if (items[3] !== "c") {
            throw "Third item in the path is not 'c' command (only relative is supported)";
        }

        let startPoint = new Point(items[1], items[2]);


        // done with "m x,y c" items
        items = items.slice(4);

        // divide by the number of points each segment has
        let segmentCount = items.length / POINTS_IN_SEGMENT;

        let segments = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < segmentCount; i++) {
            let lastSegmentEndPoint;
            if (i === 0) {
                lastSegmentEndPoint = startPoint;
            } else {
                lastSegmentEndPoint = segments[i - 1].endPoint;
            }

            // noinspection PointlessArithmeticExpressionJS
            const segment = new BezierCurveSegment(
                    // all these numbers are relative to previous segment's end point
                    // see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26675960/
                    lastSegmentEndPoint,
                    lastSegmentEndPoint.add(new Point(items[i * POINTS_IN_SEGMENT + 0], items[i * POINTS_IN_SEGMENT + 1])),
                    lastSegmentEndPoint.add(new Point(items[i * POINTS_IN_SEGMENT + 2], items[i * POINTS_IN_SEGMENT + 3])),
                    lastSegmentEndPoint.add(new Point(items[i * POINTS_IN_SEGMENT + 4], items[i * POINTS_IN_SEGMENT + 5])),
            );
            segments.push(segment);
        }

        return new BezierCurve(startPoint, segments);
    }
```

To verify it works good, I draw the points on the canvas and also draw the same path with Path2D.

```
    function drawPoints(ctx, points) {
        ctx.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
        for (let point of points) {
            ctx.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
            ctx.moveTo(point.x, point.y);
        }
        ctx.stroke();
    }

    let pathStr = 'm 776.65415,2226.6574 c 0,0 258.61385,-173.7593 289.34025,-325.8576 57.158,-282.9367 15.5277,-622.2212 50.8732,-933.13714 12.8345,-112.89946 104.2775,-278.6582 22.2568,-340.66923 -50.5144,-38.19103 -158.97817,99.97904 -158.97817,99.97904';

    const curve = createCurveFromSVGPath(pathStr);

    let pointsOnCurve = curve.getPointsOnCurve(100000);

    const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    drawPoints(ctx, pointsOnCurve);

    ctx.strokeStyle = "#FF0000";
    ctx.stroke(new Path2D(pathStr););
```